# is it possible to change packet ip with PcapSharp?

Tags: c#

i cannot find any documentation of this project

Comment: can u be the clear one ?

Comment: please try to add some more meat to the question text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this - [How does ohrwurm use libpcap and arpspoof to corrupt RTP traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761725/how-does-ohrwurm-use-libpcap-and-arpspoof-to-corrupt-rtp-traffic), libpcap (for which pcap# is a wrapper) can't make any packet modifications, it simply acts as a sniffer